# MySQL Query SELECT multiple rows

Tags: mysql, select, group-concat

I have the following table:

```
surveys
comp_id    question
4          What is your name?
4          How are you?
4          Where do you live?
5          Who are you?
5          What is your birthday?
```

I need help writing a Query that gives me the following output:

```
comp_id    my_questions
4          What is your name?How are you?Where do you live?
5          Who are you?What is your birthday?
```

Thanks,

Comment: [group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). but why do you want to 'destroy' your text like this?

Comment: Is there a grouping function in SQL that does this?

Comment: @jamis0n `group_concat` does exactly what he needs!

Comment: @Marc B: What do you mean destroy?

Comment: Awesome! Learned something new!

Comment: @Marc B: Thanks a lot MarcB. It works.

Comment: when you glue strings together like that, you make it very difficult/impossible to separate them again later on. that's fine if you're not going to be using them as individuals again, but just something to point out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function.  Use it like this:

```
SELECT comp_id, GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] question [ORDER BY some_field ASC/DESC] [SEPARATOR '']) as my_questions
FROM surveys
GROUP BY comp_id
```

Note I have shown some some optional values to pass into GROUP_CONCAT in `[]`.  To get exact like you are showing just use `GROUP_CONCAT(question SEPARATOR '')`.  The optional items let you look for distinct question values or order them by any field(s) (including question itself).

Comment: I'm doing the following query but it doesn't seem to work: "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(question) AS Questions FROM surveys WHERE question_code = 1 AND question_code = 2"

Comment: You need a `GROUP BY` clause on some field. I am actually surprised this didn't produce MySQL error as most aggregate functions do when no `GROUP BY` is present.

Comment: so if I put 'GROUP BY comp_id' without selecting comp_id, it will work?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to `SELECT` a field in order to use `GROUP BY` on it.

Comment: So... if I do this, will it work? `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(question) AS Questions FROM surveys WHERE question_code = 1 AND question_code = 2 GROUP BY comp_id`

Comment: This is because you are not selecting any records.  How can a record have `question_code = 1` AND `question_code = 2`.  A single record can have one value or the other, not BOTH.  You probably need to use `WHERE question_code IN (1,2)` or `WHERE question_code = 1 OR question_code = 2`.  The first is probably better code for dynamic queries where number of values of `question_code` that you are filtering on might vary.